# MIPS: Loading values from memory, adding them, then storing them back in memory

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

MIPS Assembly noob here using QTSPIM

```
.data

  .byte 13 

  .byte 20

  .byte 150

# Add the values up, compute the average, and store the result in a memory location.

.text
.globl main


lui $10, 0x1000          #loads the starting address of the data segment.

lb $t0, 0x10 ($10)       #supposed to load 13 into $t0.

lb $t1, 0x14  ($10)      #supposed to load 20 into $t1 

add $t1, $t0, $t1        #adds the values of t0 and t1 and stores the result in t1

lb $t2,0x18   ($10)      #supposed to load 150 into $t1 
add $t1, $t1,$t2         #adds the values of t1 and t2 and stores the result in t1.

sb $t1, 0x22 ($10)       #supposed to store the result in address 0x1022, expecting
                         # result = 183
```

I know i'm doing something wrong, but i'm not sure whether it's the addressing, or something else.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
whenever i run the program in QTSPIM, it sometimes loads the first byte correctly, and shows "d" in register 8, but doesn't add or load anythings else correctly. when i attempt to run it again, sometimes it shows a different value (usually a hex) in the same register.

I amended the coded to:

```
.data

  .byte 13 

  .byte 20

  .byte 150

# Add the values up, compute the average, and store the result in a memory location.

.text
.globl main


lui $t2, 0x1000          #loads the starting address of the data segment.

lbu $t0, 0x1 ($t2)       #supposed to load 13 into $t0.

lbu $t1, 0x2 ($t2)       #supposed to load 20 into $t1 

lbu $t3, 0x3 ($t2)       #supposed to load 150 into $t3 


add $t4, $t0, $t1        #adds the values of t0 and t1 and stores the result in t1

add $t4, $t3,$t4         #adds the values of t1 and t2 and stores the result in t1.

sb $t4, 0x13 ($t2)       #supposed to store the result in address 0x1022
```

but i'm still getting weird undesired numbers stored in the registers.

```
t0=14;
t1=96;
t2=10000000 (expected);
t3=0;
t4=aa.
```

Comment: `$10` is the same register as `$t2`, so `lb $t2, 0x18($10)` overwrites the pointer.  Don't do that, either use all ABI names like `$t0-7` or all register numbers, to avoid hidden bugs with conflicting registers.  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Register_File

Comment: Also, if `13` is at address `0x10000000` + `0x10`, the `20` byte will be at base + `0x11`, and `150` at `0x12`, because you used `.byte` to emit single bytes.  Also, a sign-extending load like `lb` will treat `150` as `-106`.  But you're later storing a byte to the result truncates back to 8 bits, so it doesn't matter whether your loads sign or zero extended.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the reply. I fixed the code (to the best of my comprehension), but i'm still getting weird numbers stored in the registers. also, for some reason, t3 is still 0 not 150.

Comment: Try looking at your data section using the debugger.

Comment: If `lui $t2, 0x1000          #loads the starting address of the data segment.` does what the comment hopes, the first `.byte` is at offset `0`, so it's actually at the start of the `.data` section where you put it.  There's no 1-byte gap.

Comment: Fyi, the default `.data` goes to 0x10010000, not 0x10000000.